# If 300 contestants line up to play this game, what is the > approximate probability that at least 150 of them win?

Tags: probability, statistics

> **Problem:** On a game show contestants play a game by putting mini-golf balls from
>   a five yard distance. Every contestant gets three chances to make a
>   put. Assume that every contestant has an equal chance of 0.2 of
>   sinking a ball. The game is won, if at least one of the three balls
>   can be sunk.

(a) What is the probability that a contestant wins this game? Which distribution
are you using and what are the parameters?
(b) How many contestants do you expect to see on average until the third one wins?
Which distribution are you using and what are the parameters?

I have a X-Bin(3,0.2)

then, P(win the game)=3C1 *0.2 (1-0.2)^2 + 3c2 * 0.2 * (1-0.2)^1 +3c2 * 0.2 ($$)^0=0.488

Point b): NB(3, 0.488) then E(y)=3/0.488=6.25

**I need help with this this point:**

> (c) If 300 contestants line up to play this game, what is the
>   approximate probability that at least 150 of them win?

I need to use normal? How? the book said the answer is 0.360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X \sim Bin(300,0.488)$. Then using the converse probability $P(X\geq 150)=1-P(X\leq 149)$

Using the De Moivre–Laplace theorem

$P(X\leq 149)\approx\Phi\left( \frac{149+0.5-n\cdot p}{\sqrt{n\cdot p\cdot (1-p)}} \right)$

+0.5 is the continuity correction factor.

$=\Phi\left( \frac{149+0.5-300\cdot 0.488}{\sqrt{300\cdot 0.488\cdot 0.512}} \right)=\Phi(0.358)$

$\Phi(0.358)$ is the value of the cdf of the standard normal distribution if $z=0.358$. If you look at [this table](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~morris/MAT135A/materials/standardnormaltable.pdf) you can see that $\Phi(0.358)$ is about $ 0.64=64\%$

Comment: If I don't missunderstand your explanation, then the probability will be 100%-64%=36%. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that´s right.

Comment: By the way you can use the converse probability to calculate the probability that at least one of the three balls can be sunk. It is 1 minus the probability that no of the three balls can be sunk: $1-0.8^3=1-0.512=0.488$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You need to use previous results ... question a.
Each candidate is a trial and it has an associated probability of success (winning the game).

Thus what you are trying to solve is: What is the probability that at least x trials are successful among N trials with probability p.

I think that you can find what distribution to use and what are the parameters...